# Retrieve information from firebase doesn't work, key is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to solve it like this: 
[How to pull out data from firebase into html page - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464626/how-to-pull-out-data-from-firebase-into-html-page)

But I couldn't get it to work.

My html looks where I'll put the information from Firebase looks this in javascript:

```
var createTable = "<table><thead><tr id='keysRow'></tr></thead>";
var endHead = "<tbody><tr id='valuesRow'></tr></tbody></table>";  

//More code that's connecting to each other and displays it in a div.
//F12 is showing me that this works.
```

Firebase.js:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var v = firebase.database();

var users = firebase.database().ref("users");


users.orderByKey().once('child_added', function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot){

var key = childsnapshot.key(); <---------error
var data = childsnapshot.val();

$('#keysRow').append('<th>' + key + '</th>');
$('#valuesRow').append('<td>' + data + '</td>');
});
});
```

config is just the link to the firebase. I have no problem using the config to write in the firebase.

> The error is telling me: "childsnapshot.key is not a function"

Also my firebase has 10 different values I need to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var key = childsnapshot.key();
```

to this:

```
var key = childsnapshot.key;
```

check this link to see what has changed in Firebase 3.x: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Comment: Thanks :D
Next problem: $ is not defined  <-- at $('#keysRow').append('<th>' + key + '</th>');

Comment: that is another problem not related to this question, but you can check this to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined . You may have your javascript file before the jquery script (check the link to solve it)